# How is the effect (swash) achieved?

Tags: fonts

Sorry, I don't know the name of this typographic effect, it's been years since I read *The Elements of Typographic Style*. This is more than kerning. I'm referring to the "tail" of the N going under the following letters. Or is it a particular font with this feature?

[image]

The image is from page 2 of http://www.tsengbooks.com/images/6176s.pdf

I'll update the question if I learn the proper typographical term.

Thank you.

**Update**: as Lev Bishop indicated, the effect is called swash ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swash_(typography)))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a feature of the font. You can see the same thing with the Q in the 'swash' style of Minion Pro. Eg.,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
\textsw{Queen}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need any special engine. As I showed above, the MinionPro package sets up a swash style (accessed by `\textsw{}`) for the MinionPro fonts, even with latex or pdflatex.